# Getting a keyerror when accessing the list in a dictionary using _getitem_() function

Tags: python, python-2.7

I have a dictionary

```
title_data = {'1':['City','State','Town']}
```

and I would like to get the State value so I use `title_data['1']._getitem_(1)` and I get a keyerror, even though I checked and that key is in the dictionary.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`title_data['1']` already gives you the value for '1' in the dictionary: a list. get the second element using `title_data['1'][1]`.

```
>>> title_data = {'1':['City','State','Town']}
>>> title_data['1'][1]
'State'
```

It is spelled `__getitem__` (double underscore at each side; `_getitem_` will give you `AttributeError`). You will probably never need to use it (that's what the underscore is for), but if you do, it works perfectly:

```
>>> title_data['1'].__getitem__(1)
'State'
```

I don't know how did you get the `KeyError`; maybe you did `title_data[1].__getitem__(1)` or something like that.

Comment: Yes but I want to get the value of the 2nd index of that list. So I want the value State and not all of the list.

Comment: I get the same keyerror. When I go into debug mode the key value exist in the dictionary but when I hit this line of code title_data['1'][1] in the key value it says "wait" and in the value part it says "for network" very odd.

Comment: the data is not what you think it is.

Answer (score 0):

If you execute:

```
title_data = {'1':['City','State','Town']}
title_data['1']._getitem_(1)
```

in python 2.7 you get an **AttributeError** because the list that is returned by `title_data['1']` has no method `_getitem_`.

You are missing the **double** underscore: `__getitem__()`:

```
title_data = {'1':['City','State','Town']}
title_data['1'].__getitem__(1)
```

works, as does of course the more commonly used:

```
title_data = {'1':['City','State','Town']}
title_data['1'][1]
```